What is exactly a principal component in PCA
Given a data matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$
The PCA algorithm is computing the covariance matrix $C$ of the centered data matrix $\bar{X}$ and then diagonalizing it
$$C=VLV^{T}$$
Are the "principal components" the columns of $V$ or the projection of the data matrix with $\bar{X}V$?
And what is the relationship of this procedure to taking the SVD of the data matrix and having $X=USV^{T}$?  Are the "principal components" equal to the ones using the covariance matrix?
